# Fontawesome Icon not working as state value on React with TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

I am using an icon dynamically, so I would change the type of the icon with a state update, but I'm getting this error:
`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IconPrefix'.`

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import  { useState } from 'react'

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

const Produto = () => {
   const [wishlistIcon, setWishlistIcon] = useState('far')
   
   return (
      <FontAwesomeIcon 
         icon={[wishlistIcon, 'heart']} size="2x"  
      />
   )
}

export default Produto
```

But if I pass the string directly as the icon value it works fine:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

const Produto = () => {
   
   return (
      <FontAwesomeIcon 
         icon={['far', 'heart']} size="2x"  
      />
   )
}

export default Produto
```

Is there a way in which I could use this value as a state?

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions. I'm not sure if any of them is a good approach (it would be good if someone could clarify that for me), but they both work.

The first one is to import the `IconPrefix` from `fontawesome-svg-core` and set it as the type of the state. I'm going with that one:

```
import { IconPrefix } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
const [wishlistIcon, setWishlistIcon] = useState<IconPrefix>('far')
```

The second on is to go directly to the source of the type `IconPrefix` and add `string` as one of its types: - NOT RECOMMENDED

```
export type IconPrefix = "fas" | "far" | "fal" | "fat" | "fad" | "fab" | "fak" | string ;
```

EDIT:

The second solution works, but it is not a good approach, since it will work in your machine, but once you (or anyone else) have to reinstall the project's dependencies, `IconPrefix` will be restored to its original values and your project will break.

The first approach is ok, but today (with more knowledge to understand what is happening) I would create a new type with the values I want to use, so TS will know that I'm following its rules and only using allowed values:

```
type Icon = 'fas' | 'far'
const [wishlistIcon, setWishlistIcon] = useState<Icon>('far')
```

That way no extra type need to be imported.